# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function onclick

Tags: javascript, function, object, onclick

I receive the error "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" when clicking on a button in my webpage.

The button code is:

`<button id="addUser" name="addUser" onclick="addUser()"> Add User </button>`

The code for function addUser is

```
function addUser() {

    userValue = document.getElementById("userForAdmin");
    passValue = document.getElementById("passForAdmin");
    console.log(userValue.value);
    console.log(passValue.value);
}
```

Can anyone point out my error? My guess is its likely a basic mistake.

Comment: That code seems fine. Can you reproduce this with a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: Keep function name different, say addUSer1

Answer (score 6):

Use different names for the function and the element ID. When you do `id="addUser"`, that creates a global variable `window.addUser` that refers to the DOM element. This is overriding the function definition with that name.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome though http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/m95eq3cz/